# Which one is considered the departure time of a commercial flight?

Tags: commercial-aviation, time

I was wondering, the publicly announced departure time of a commercial flight, is it the ETOT (estimated takeoff time) or is it the [EOBT](http://www.eurocontrol.int/lexicon/lexicon/en/index.php/Estimated_Off-Block_Time) (estimated off-block time)? Or maybe some other time?

Comment: Ticketing questions would be a better fit on Travel.se

Comment: @TomMcW I removed the references to the tickets. Hope it's better now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scheduled time is the EOBT. Flights that depart within 15 minutes of it are considered on-time.
Standard taxi times for each airport are included in the scheduled flight time.

Comment: Not [SOBT](http://www.eurocontrol.int/lexicon/lexicon/en/index.php/Scheduled_Off-Block_Time)? Either way, definitely some form of BLOCK OUT time, rather than TAKE OFF time is what's on the ticket.

Comment: @Ralph J Good point. Surely SOBT. Didn't remember the term at all. Main point still remains: off-block, not take-off.

Comment: Nice. That's what I thought as well. It would also be nice to include a source of information for completeness.

Comment: @Stelios My source is my training, can't name the documents :D

Answer (score -1):

In [this document](http://www.euro-cdm.org/library/airports/cdg/data_sheet_nr3.pdf) you will find some of the many timestamps used in CDM.
As you can see there, the EOBT is the timestamp displayed in the flight plan.

The time on the ticket usually corresponds to the ETA/ETD which in term should be STOT (scheduled take-off time).

Are you extracting information from a data source or are you just curious?

Comment: Welcome to aviation SE. I'm just curious. That part of the answer could have better been a comment on the question. :)

Comment: Answer is wrong. The ticket shows the PUSH time - block out time. How much later than that takeoff will occur is transparent to the passenger.

Comment: @RalphJ: why is the answer wrong? Source? PUSH is not an offical time stamp

Comment: I work in the industry. Time on your ticket is the time we're scheduled to push back from the gate, also known as blocking out. We'll take off some time after that, but this time isn't on the ticket or any passenger-facing published schedule. BTW, that document you linked doesn't say anything like what your answer says about T/O time being published on the ticket.

Comment: If you have a look at http://www.eurocontrol.int/lexicon/lexicon/en/index.php/Target_Off-Block_Time it states, that this is an airline / handling agent estimate. I also know, that TOBT is a commitment from the airline (no source though). What exactly do you mean, when you say industry? Airline/airport/handling agent? Also usa/eu? There are differences.

Comment: So here [1] is quite the explanation on all the CDM timestamps. It explains that TOBT is an AO commitment, where AO is the aircraft operator, which may or may not be the same as the airline. Still no relation to times that might be on a ticket. For me this only leaves the explanation, that there is no real relation between the two. There certainly is no standard on how they should be calculated.

[1] http://cdm.frankfurt-airport.com/content/fraport-ag-cdm/en/misc/binaer/documents/a-cdm_procedure_poster/jcr:content.file/acdm_procedure_poster.pdf